# Bring back the suggested edit notifications to the top bar

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, top-bar

It appears that the suggested edit indicator (to users with the “moderator tools” privilege) has disappeared from the new top bar.

The suggested edit indicator is useful. Suggested edit review is not like other review tasks which can wait until somebody's interested in doing moderation. A pending suggested edit on a post locks the post against modifications by users without the edit privilege. Without the indicator, posts will spend longer in that semi-locked state. That's not good.

Please bring back an apparent notification of pending suggested edits.