# Orange link that used to be suggested edits is now all review

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, top-bar

When I reached 2k reputation points (on Stack Overflow), I got an orange rectangle next to my profile link on the notification bar that links to the suggested edits review page and displays the number of pending edits.

[image: screenshot]

Since I reached 10k, that link now displays a much bigger number and links to the whole review page, not just suggested edits.  I don't like that because I already have a link to the review page right next to it.  The suggested edits queue is my favorite thing to review, so I liked having a quick way of getting to it.  Now, it's two clicks: review; suggested edits.  I would like it if that link stayed the same as it was.

Comment: Congrats for reaching 10k! I'm afraid this is long time behavior (years back) and sure someone already asked to change it, will find the dupe shortly.

Comment: I was bit wrong. Closest match is [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230874/bring-back-the-suggested-edits-notifications-to-the-top-bar-again), which is (wrongfully iMO) marked as completed. Leaving this one on its own then.

Comment: [Here's the original feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191638/300411).  Possible duplicate: [Review Count - Fix It or Lose It](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238472/300411).  Related feature request: [Please dim the color of the review task counter when there are no actionable tasks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231051/300411)

Comment: @Shadow That question was about the lower threshold to make *any* indicator appear at all, and *was* changed.

Comment: @animuson changed, but not in the way OP asked for. The request is "show number of suggested edits in the top bar" - that did not happen. Maybe a step towards it, but surely not the whole thing.

Comment: @Nathaniel thanks, I've somehow missed [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238472/300411) while searching even though I posted an answer there!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I don't consider it a duplicate.  I am asking for it to be moved back to suggested edits, but the other question is asking for it to be removed altogether.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, you're saying it was incorrectly completed, which is not true. The request in *that* question was completed. It's just a completely different request.

Comment: @zondo no, you misunderstood the other question. In the past, the number used to show only suggested edits count, even for 10k users. It was changed at some point, and that request is asking to undo this change, meaning have it show only suggested edits count, regardless of the user reputation.

Comment: @animuson if I ask for an apple, and get an orange, will you call it "completed" because they're both fruits? Anyway, since I can't do anything anyway guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Shadow The other question was about the threshold for the indicator to *appear* being set too high (10), and they didn't even know there were items to review - there was stuff in the queue but they didn't know it was there. It had nothing to do with which review indicator should be displayed. It was completed because we lowered the threshold (to 3) for the indicator to display on most sites, so they are notified much sooner.